# Text only HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a HTML button that appears as only text.  My HTML must be completely semantic using external CSS and JS files.

I have been having a lot of trouble with this as I can't get the placement right nor can I get the background of the button to disappear.

```css
#bttnPlacement {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

myBttn {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <img src="/images/gameTitle.jpg" alt="Banner">
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <h>What Is Your Choice?</h>
  <p>1. Be a Banker from Boston</p>
  <p>2. Be a Carpenter from Ohio</p>
  <p>3. Be a Farmer from Illinois</p>
  <p>4. Learn About the Differences</p>
</div>
<div id="bttnPlacement">
  <button id="myBttn">
                Press Spacebar to Return to Main Menu        
            </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean like an `a` tag?

Comment: What does JavaScript have to do with this?

Comment: because I'm using javascript to add functionality, so I tagged it in case there is some element of that involved here

Comment: So if you want to style the button why are you apply the styles to the div element used to wrap the button? Shouldn't you be adding the css to the button?

Comment: If you want something to not be a button then don't make it a button. Use a `<div>` or something else you can attach a click Event to. If you're trying to link it to another page use `<a>` with `text-decoration:none;` in the CSS.

Comment: @ifconfig I considered that, but didn't know if that would be considered semantic or not, I'm fairly new to this

Comment: @mzaccaro89 `a` tags are the best way to do that.

Comment: Regarding your button's text, "Press Spacebar to Return to Main Menu", pressing space won't press the button unless focus is on the button, so isn't that a bit confusing for the user? Anyway, using anchor elements is the standard way to control general page navigation, whereas buttons would normally be used to navigate when a form submit is involved, or to do "wizard" style Next/Prev navigation.

Comment: @nnnnnn I've got a JS event to handle when the user presses the spacebar, I wanted functionality for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your background transparent as text only, you need to overwrite the default button css

```
button {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}

button:focus {
    outline: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty close, but you are targeting the wrong element.

```css
#myBttn {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <img src="/images/gameTitle.jpg" alt="Banner">
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <h>What Is Your Choice?</h>
  <p>1. Be a Banker from Boston</p>
  <p>2. Be a Carpenter from Ohio</p>
  <p>3. Be a Farmer from Illinois</p>
  <p>4. Learn About the Differences</p>
</div>
<div id="bttnPlacement">
  <button id="myBttn">
                Press Spacebar to Return to Main Menu        
            </button>
</div>
```

I only changed the selector of the first class, to match the `button`, instead of its container `div` element.

Answer (score 0):

Trade

```
<button id="myBttn">
              Press Spacebar to Return to Main Menu        
          </button>
```

out with

```
<a id='myBttn' href='index.php'>Press Spacebar to Return to Main Menu</a>
```

*(of course with the proper menu URL)* then do

```
#myBttn:link,#myBttn:hover,#myBttn:active,#myBttn:visited{
  text-decoration:none; color:#000;
}
```

in your CSS. Feel free to change that color.

Comment: so this works, should I give the url of the html file? because when I click the link it returns `cannot GET /mainMenu.html` or can i set up a JS event to handle the location considering I've been using express for routing?

Answer (score 0):

Here you Press space you will see and use

```
background:unset;
border:unset
```

In here you try to select your button with its id. If you want to select as ID you must Declare this `#` before `idname`

```
#myBttn { //added # for select as id
  text-align: center;
}
```

```js
$(window).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    alert('Your Action in here')
  }
})
```

```css
#bttnPlacement {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myBttn {
  text-align: center;
  background: unset;
  border: unset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner">
  <img src="" alt="Banner">
</div>
<div class="menu">
  <h>What Is Your Choice?</h>
  <p>1. Be a Banker from Boston</p>
  <p>2. Be a Carpenter from Ohio</p>
  <p>3. Be a Farmer from Illinois</p>
  <p>4. Learn About the Differences</p>
</div>
<div id="bttnPlacement">
  <button id="myBttn">
                Press Spacebar to Return to Main Menu        
            </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        #bttnPlacement {
            text-align: center;
            height: 100px;
            width: 300px;
        }

        #myBttn {
            text-align: center;
            /*color: white;*/
            background: transparent;
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            display: block;
            cursor: pointer;

        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="banner">
            <img src="/images/gameTitle.jpg" alt="Banner">
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <h>What Is Your Choice?</h>
            <p>1. Be a Banker from Boston</p>
            <p>2. Be a Carpenter from Ohio</p>
            <p>3. Be a Farmer from Illinois</p>
            <p>4. Learn About the Differences</p>
        </div>
        <div id="bttnPlacement">
            <button id="myBttn">
                Press Spacebar to Return to Main Menu
            </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question's comments point to better answers, which seem to indicate JavaScript is a better path for this problem. The question also requires JS and CSS to be kept separate.